# Prove every prtial order R has a full order S such that R$\subseteq$S

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*sorry for bad english in advance

The question was:

Let A a group and let R be a pratial order of A. Prove that there exists a full order S of A such that R$\subseteq$S.

hint: Use Zorn's lemma.

I started the proof like that:

Let F be the group which every elemnt of F is a prtial order of A such that for every $K\in F: R\subseteq K$ with the $\subseteq$ order.

Let C be a chain in F. Let $D=\bigcup C$.

It's pretty obvious that D is an upper bound of C so using Zorn's lemma we found there exists a maximum H.

Now let's assume H isn't a full order. That means there exists $x,y\in A$ such that $(x,y)\land (y,x)\notin H$.

Let $H'=H\cup (x,y)$.

Now I want to show H' is a pratial order and then we found a contradiction to that H is a maximum in F(because $H\subsetneqq H'$).

To show that H' is reflexive and anti-symetry is pretty easy. But how do I show that H' is transitive? how can I be sure that if $(y,z)\in H'$ then $(x,z)\in H'$?

Comment: $H'$ in general isn't a partial order. You need to consider the transitive closure of $H'$, not $H'$ itself

Comment: Our lecturer gave us the definition at the start of the course but didn't really talk about it. The transitive closure stays anti symtery or it can lose it's anti symtery?

Comment: It can "loose it" in general, but here you can try to prove that it doesn't.

Comment: I managed to prove that, thanks a lot! :D